# Cross section of a plane in a cube

Tags: 3d, plane-geometry, polygons

A plane is going through a cube so the cross section is a pentagon. Prove that the area of the pentagon is smaller than the product of the pentagon's two largest sides.

[image: A sketch]

The first thing I tried to do was to express some of the sides through pythagorean theorem, however i failed to do so as not all sides are a part of a right triangle. I don't have any idea after this.

Comment: Hint: The pentagon is completely determined by the distances of $A, B, $ and $C$ to the bottom face.

Comment: @JoshuaWang I don't see that.  Why can't we move $D$ and $$E along the edges after having fixed $A,B,$ and $C$?

Comment: @saulspatz Because $A,B,C$ will already determine the plane of the pentagon

Comment: @Andrei Oh, duh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sharing an approach that you can turn into a more formal proof -

The point to observe is that if the cross section of the cube cut by the plane is a pentagon, it must go through $5$ sides of the cube and two pairs of sides must be  parallel (that are on parallel sides of the cube). Here is a visualization -

[image]

In the diagram, we have $AB \parallel ED, AE \parallel BC$ and
$AB \gt DE$ and $AE \gt BC$.

If we extend line $ED$ and line $BC$ and say they meet at point $M$ then we have a parallelogram $ABME$.

WLOG, $AB$ is the longer side and $AE$ is the smaller side of the parallelogram $ABME$.

Area of pentagon $ \lt$ area of parallelogram ABME $ \leq \ AB \cdot AE \leq P, $ where $P$ is the product of the two largest sides of the pentagon.

So the inequality clearly hold even if $DE \gt AE \ $ or $CD \gt AE$ or $AB$.

Comment: I like the approach. You would need to consider the length of $DC$ as well.

Comment: @Andrei thanks. You are right about $DC$. I just edited.